# Accessing or Controlling the SRV CNAME in Headless Services

Tags: kubernetes

When creating a headless service in Kubernetes, it auto-generates the CNAME for each pod. I need to access this hostname somehow on pod boot. I can't seem to find it in the downward API or set in any kind of environment variable. Where can I get this value from within the pod itself, or is it even possible?

Right now running `dig` on the service returns the following:

```
_etcd-server._tcp.etcd.databases.svc.cluster.local. 30  IN  SRV 10 100 2380 3730623862383630.etcd.databases.svc.cluster.local.
```

At the very least I need the `3730623862383630` portion of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to treat your pods as pets, not cattle. Maybe you can try to use [`PetSet`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/)s and headless `Service`? Then you will have the [DNS entry](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/#network-identity) like `etcd-0.databases.svc.cluster.local` which [can be used during startup](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/#peer-discovery).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use pet sets on GKE yet. Great response. Once I can use `PetSet`s, the bounty may be yours.